How to focus YouTube search suggestions items?
I currently have this code. This opens the YT search in a new tab when you click the middle-mouse button:
(function() {
    'use strict';
 
    var searchIcon = document.getElementById("search-icon-legacy");
    if (searchIcon) {
        searchIcon.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var searchInput = document.getElementsByClassName("ytd-searchbox")[3].value.trim();
            if (event.which === 2 && searchInput) {
                window.open("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + encodeURIComponent(searchInput), "_blank");
            }
        });
    }
})();

Picture
I'm now trying to focus the search suggestions by middle-clicking them, but I'm struggling because I don't know how to bring them into focus like the search button, which is an element.

What does this mean: trying to focus the search suggestions by middle-clicking them? The first part -- opening the YT Search in a new Tab -- I can imagine. But I cannot picture what you are trying to do in the 2nd part. Exactly what are you middle-clicking ON, and what should happen when you middle-click on it? Sorry for being obtuse, but requesting that you please explain in a little more detail / clarity.

Sorry that I didn't describe it clearly. When hovering the mouse cursor over a search item, it should capture the text from the item and open it as a search result in a new tab by clicking the middle mouse button.

@JuliusEsen the suggestions are returned by a request. You could try to get the suggestions if you inspect the sbsb_b element. Example: document.getElementsByClassName("sbsb_b")[0].childNodes and then read the outerText of every childNode.

@MauricioAriasOlave Can you give me a useful approach or a good method? Is the const declaration a good support in this case?

if what you want is to open the one of the search suggestions in another tab using a middle-mouse click, then this should work:
function callback(event){
    if (!event.button === 1) return; // return if not middle button
    const ele = event.target.closest('div.sbqs_c');
    if (!ele) return; // guard incase it's wrong element because we are listening on `body` instead of `<ul>`
    const url = `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=${encodeURIComponent(ele.textContent)}`;
    window.open(url, '_blank');
}

document.body.addEventListener('auxclick', callback);

you can add the 'auxclick' listener to the specific element (ul.sbsb_b) instead of the body, but you'll have to use a mutation observer for that, since the suggestions box does not load until the user interacts with the search box.

@GTK Thank you!
I added your to my current updated code and it works :)
(function() {
    'use strict';

    function callback(event){
        if (event.button !== 1) return; // return if not middle button
        const ele = event.target.closest('div.sbqs_c');
        if (!ele) return; // guard in case it's the wrong element because we are listening on `body` instead of `<ul>`
        const url = `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=${encodeURIComponent(ele.textContent.trim())}`;
        window.open(url, '_blank');
    }

    document.body.addEventListener('auxclick', callback);

    // MutationObserver to observe changes in the DOM
    const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
        const suggestions = document.querySelectorAll('div.sbqs_c');
        suggestions.forEach(suggestion => {
            suggestion.removeEventListener('auxclick', callback); // Ensure no duplicate listeners
            suggestion.addEventListener('auxclick', callback);
        });
    });

    // Configuration of the observer
    observer.observe(document.body, {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true
    });
})();

